# neo4j SOH character as delimiter is supported?

Tags: import, neo4j

I have a csv that has as delimiter SOH character does neo4j import tool support  this character ? through load csv i succeded to with fieldterminator '.' in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it possible - you need use [escape sequence](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/#_note_on_string_literals) of SOH character:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///soh.csv" as row FIELDTERMINATOR "\u0001"
RETURN row
```

[For command line](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.2/community/import-tool/src/main/java/org/neo4j/tooling/CharacterConverter.java#L27):

> String expression can be normal characters as well as for example:
>   '\t', '\123', and "TAB".

```
../bin/neo4j-import --into ./db/ --nodes soh.csv --delimiter "\0001"
```

Comment: OK thanks.And in import command which delimiter should I pass? I tried --delimiter  "\u0001" and got unsupported character

Comment: @sandra For command line simply omit the symbol `u`: --delimiter "\0001"